# One jar library for Android and Java (One compiled library for both)

Tags: java, android, jar

I'm writing a Java library that uses some classes available in Android and other in AWT (Like android Bitmap and JWT BufferedImage).
I use these classes internally (None of them public).

Now I want both of them to be in same jar (I added checking (If Android or not) before calling any of these specific classes).

I tried it and it works fine.

Now the question, Is this safe, or there might be any problem that will face the users of this library when using it in their apps (Java or Android)?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. But why? The only issue is duplicate libraries in Android Studio can sometimes cause problems. So if you ever import one of those two libraries again for whatever reason Android Studio will freak out at you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I'm trying to write is one library only (One compiled library for both of them .... There will be no duplication